# How to rename multiple PowerBi reports in Dev, QA, PROD during CICD using Azure DevOps Yaml Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, cicd

In my repository, I have 2 PowerBi reports (.pbix files) in a folder:

- Report1.pbix
- Report2.pbix

In my Yaml pipeline, I am creating an artifact named "reports" and coping all the reports there in the **CI** step.

Then in the **CD** steps (Dev, Qa, and Prod), I am deploying them using **PowerBIActions@5** task. Everything is working as expected. But I want to rename them in each environment.

For Example in DEV:

- DEV - Report1.pbix
- DEV - Report2.pbix

For Example in QA:

- QA - Report1.pbix
- QA - Report2.pbix

For Example in PROD:

- PROD - Report1.pbix
- PROD - Report2.pbix

This should be generic, in the future, I can have more reports. I have used copy files task but it does not have the option to provide the destination filename. There are other options like CmdLine **ren**, Powershell Rename-Item, and Powershell Copy-Item but they copy or rename a single file at a time. But in my case, there are 2 reports and the number of reports will increase in the future. So I do not want to put multiple Rename-Item tasks for each report. I think a loop or something else is required. Guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just leave the names the same and deploy them to DEV, QA, and PROD workspaces?

Comment: I am deploying them to Dev, Qa, and Prod workspaces but still, management wants them to have separate names. :)

Comment: Management should care about Prod only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is a sample for 'Dev-'. You can capture the current environment and rename all of the '.pbix' files.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    dir
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      #foreach folder and rename files with specific suffix
      import os
      import re
      
      def rename_files(path,env):
          for file in os.listdir(path):
              if file.endswith(".pbix"):
                  os.rename(file , env+file)
                  print(file)
                  print(os.path.join(path, file))
              else:
                  pass
      
      rename_files(".","Dev-")
- script: |
    dir
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

Successfully on my side:

[image]

After rename the files, copy them to target place.